# MVC4 WebApi Routing with ActionNames not allowing for generic "Get"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I've been having trouble trying to be able to have multiple "Get" methods while also having a default of /api/{controller}. Here is an example with dummy code (yes I realize it would return the exact same).

Error: `"Multiple actions were found that match the request"` when I try to go to `/api/courses`

Going to `/api/courses/all` works fine and so does `/api/courses/3`

```
// GET api/courses
public IEnumerable<Courses> Get()
{
    return Db.Courses.OrderBy(x => x.Name);
}

// GET api/courses/all
[ActionName("all")]
public IEnumerable<Courses> GetAll()
{
    return Db.Courses.OrderBy(x => x.Name);
}

// GET api/courses/id
[ActionName("all")]
public Courses Get(int id)
{
    return Db.Courses.Where(x => x.id == id);
}
```

`RouteConfig` looks like:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
       "ApiControllerOnly",
       "api/{controller}"
);

// Allow for numeric Ids to be passed in
routes.MapHttpRoute(
       "ApiControllerAndIntegerId",
       "api/{controller}/{id}",
       null,
       new { id = @"^\d+$" }
);

routes.MapHttpRoute(
       "ApiControllerAction",
       "api/{controller}/{action}"
);
```

What I want to be able to do is call:

```
/api/courses - returns Get()
/api/courses/all - returns GetAll()
/api/courses/3 - returns Get(id = 3)
```

Edit:

It also needs to allow for Put, Post, etc to work as well such as `Putting` a course on /api/courses/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Error: "Multiple actions were found that match the request" when I try to go to /api/courses

By specifying the default action to be "Get" for the `ApiControllerOnly` route, I was able to get `/api/courses` to work.  Does this work for your scenario?

```
        routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ApiControllerOnly",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}",
            defaults: new { action = "Get" }
        );
```

### Edit:

If you have additional Put/Post/etc methods in you APIController, you should consider using `HttpMethodConstraint` on the `ApiControllerOnly` route and add another route (i.e. `ApiControllerOnly2`) for the Put/Post/etc methods:

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ApiControllerOnly",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}",
            defaults: new { action = @"Get" },
            constraints: new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Get) }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ApiControllerOnly2",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}"
        );
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ApiControllerAndIntegerId",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: null,
            constraints: new { id = @"^\d+$" }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ApiControllerAction",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}"
        );
```

Comment: Wow I was trying to make it too complicated... I had to remove the first route to get it to work, but yes adding a default for "action" worked on my "ApiControllerAction" version. Sad to think how long I spent on this before coming to SO :(

Comment: I just realized that this breaks any Put, Post or other actions :(

Comment: in this case your scenario here is different from what you have described... You will need to add additional routes to support the different actions...

Comment: Do you know how I'd get that to work? The Put, Post, etc work fine if I leave in the original `ApiControllerOnly` version but then I lose out on the ability to have multiple "Gets" and a default.

Comment: I have edited my original response to answer your question in getting the Put/Post/etc methods to work...

Comment: ahhh thank you, I'll try it out. I had to change `new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Get)` to `new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Get.Method)` since it is expecting a string

Comment: Make sure you're using the HttpMethodConstraint from the System.Web.Http.Routing namespace (instead of the one from System.Web.Routing)...

Comment: Ah yeah, I was using the System.Web.Routing since it was needed for the map routing... why would they have two :(. Thanks again Maggie! :)